# ngAria support for Safari Browser

Tags: google-chrome, safari, keyboard, accessibility, wai-aria

I have added ngAria in my code base and it works well in Chrome browser. But, It didn't work in Safari Browser. Is there anything I should code specific to Safari browser for keyboard accessibility to work.

Thanks,
Ramesh

Answer (score 0):

Got a solution for this. I checked System preferences of my machine and made changes to them as mentioned in this http://www.weba11y.com/blog/2014/07/07/keyboard-navigation-in-mac-browsers/